# Calling an async function in another file and using .then there

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, redux

I'm trying to call the async function getFunc() my bodyOfApp.component.js, from my getFunc.js file and use .then to use it's returned value

### getFunc.js

```
import React from "react";

import { connect } from "react-redux";

import timeDiff from "./timeDiff";

import { currentProjectData } from "./redux/projectData/projectData.actions";

const getFunc = async () => {

    let dataOfTripCard = {};

    const create_UUID = () => {
        var dt = new Date().getTime();
        var uuid = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function (c) {
            var r = (dt + Math.random() * 16) % 16 | 0;
            dt = Math.floor(dt / 16);
            return (c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8)).toString(16);
        });
        return uuid;
    }

    const username = //my username (string value);
    const weatherbitAPIKey = //my weatherbit APIKey (string value);
    const pixabayAPIKey = //my pixabay APIKey username (string value);

    const baseURLGeo = "http://api.geonames.org/searchJSON?q=";
    const baseURLWeatherCurrent = "https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/current?";
    const baseURLWeatherForecast = "https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/forecast/daily?";
    const baseURLPixabay = "https://pixabay.com/api/?";

    const city = this.props.currentInputs.city;
    const depDateFromUser = this.props.currentInputs.depDateFromUser;
    const returnDateFromUser = this.props.currentInputs.returnDateFromUser;

    // Create a new date instance dynamically with JS
    const d = new Date();
    const newDate = d.getMonth() + 1 + '/' + d.getDate() + '/' + d.getFullYear();

    const resGeo = await fetch(baseURLGeo + encodeURI(city) + "&username=" + username);

    try {
        const data = await resGeo.json();
        const countryName = data.geonames[0].countryName;
        const latitude = data.geonames[0].lat;
        const longitude = data.geonames[0].lng;
        const daysLeft = timeDiff(newDate, depDateFromUser, returnDateFromUser);

        const resWeather = await fetch(
            ((daysLeft > 7) ? baseURLWeatherForecast : baseURLWeatherCurrent) + "key=" + weatherbitAPIKey + "&lat=" + latitude + "&lon=" + longitude
        );

        const data2 = await resWeather.json();
        const weather = data2.data[0].weather.description;

        const resPixabayPhoto = await fetch(baseURLPixabay + "key=" + pixabayAPIKey + "&q=" + encodeURI(city) + "+tourism&image_type=photo");

        const data3 = await resPixabayPhoto.json();
        const cityPhoto = data3.hits[0].webformatURL;

        // id generated by create_UUID function
        const currentId = create_UUID();

        const tripData = {
            cityPhoto: cityPhoto,
            country: countryName,
            date: newDate,
            depDate: depDateFromUser,
            retDate: returnDateFromUser,
            daysLeft: daysLeft,
            weather: weather,
            temp: (daysLeft > 7) ? {
                low_temp: data2.data[0].low_temp,
                max_temp: data2.data[0].max_temp,
                trueOrFalse: true //For the if statement in updateUI in the client side
            } : {
                    temp: data2.data[0].temp,
                    trueOrFalse: false //For the if statement in updateUI in the client side
                },
            lat: latitude,
            lng: longitude,
            tripId: currentId
        };

        dataOfTripCard[currentId] = tripData;

        return dataOfTripCard;

    } catch (error) {
        console.log("error", error);
        //appropriately handle the error
    }

};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    currentInputs: state.inputs.currentInputs
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    currentProjectData: projectData => dispatch(currentProjectData(projectData))
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(getFunc);
```

### bodyOfApp.component.js

```
import React from "react";

import { connect } from "react-redux";

import { currentInputs } from "../../redux/inputs/inputs.actions";
import { toggleSubmittedOrNot } from "../../redux/pop-up/pop-up.actions";
import { toggleShowPopUp } from "../../redux/pop-up/pop-up.actions";
import { currentProjectData } from "../../redux/projectData/projectData.actions";

import MyTripsHolder from "../myTripsHolder/myTripsHolder.component";

import getFunc from "../../getFunc";

import './bodyOfApp.styles.scss'    

class BodyOfApp extends React.Component {

performAction = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();


//some code here

getFunc().then((dataOfTripCard) => {
  this.props.currentProjectData({
     dataOfTripCard
  })
});
}
 
render() {
     return (
       //jsx code here
     )
  }
}

   

//and at the bottom of the file:
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  currentInputs: inputs => dispatch(currentInputs(inputs)),
  toggleSubmittedOrNot: popUp => dispatch(toggleSubmittedOrNot(popUp)),
  toggleShowPopUp: () => dispatch(toggleShowPopUp()),
  currentProjectData: projectData => dispatch(currentProjectData(projectData))
    })


export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(BodyOfApp);
```

But I'm getting this error:
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

[image: Here's the TypeError screenshot]

Is the way I'm calling the getFunc() async function in the other file (bodyOfApp.component.js), wrong? If it is, how should I go about calling it?

Comment: "Here's the link to my project on Github" — That's a 404 error … and questions shouldn't depend on external resources to be understood anyway.

Comment: Okay, thank you, I removed the Github link now

Comment: It looks like `getFunc` isn't actually exported in getFunc.js. The only export is the default export of the connected component. So when you do `import getFunc from "../../getFunc";` you're getting the result of the `connect()` call, not the async function itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `connect` function of redux will return something else than you've anticipated. I would suggest not using any redux connections but allow the `getFunc` function to accept arguments which will be passed the `BodyOfApp` component.

Also using `this` in an arrow function will leave the scope of the function and not reference the `getFunc` function.

```
const getFunc = async (currentInputs) => {

  let dataOfTripCard = {};

  const create_UUID = () => {
    var dt = new Date().getTime();
    var uuid = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
      var r = (dt + Math.random() * 16) % 16 | 0;
      dt = Math.floor(dt / 16);
      return (c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8)).toString(16);
    });
    return uuid;
  }

  const username = //my username (string value);
  const weatherbitAPIKey = //my weatherbit APIKey (string value);
  const pixabayAPIKey = //my pixabay APIKey username (string value);

  const baseURLGeo = "http://api.geonames.org/searchJSON?q=";
  const baseURLWeatherCurrent = "https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/current?";
  const baseURLWeatherForecast = "https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/forecast/daily?";
  const baseURLPixabay = "https://pixabay.com/api/?";

  const city = currentInputs.city;
  const depDateFromUser = currentInputs.depDateFromUser;
  const returnDateFromUser = currentInputs.returnDateFromUser;

  // Create a new date instance dynamically with JS
  const d = new Date();
  const newDate = d.getMonth() + 1 + '/' + d.getDate() + '/' + d.getFullYear();

  const resGeo = await fetch(baseURLGeo + encodeURI(city) + "&username=" + username);

  try {
    const data = await resGeo.json();
    const countryName = data.geonames[0].countryName;
    const latitude = data.geonames[0].lat;
    const longitude = data.geonames[0].lng;
    const daysLeft = timeDiff(newDate, depDateFromUser, returnDateFromUser);

    const resWeather = await fetch(
      ((daysLeft > 7) ? baseURLWeatherForecast : baseURLWeatherCurrent) + "key=" + weatherbitAPIKey + "&lat=" + latitude + "&lon=" + longitude
    );

    const data2 = await resWeather.json();
    const weather = data2.data[0].weather.description;

    const resPixabayPhoto = await fetch(baseURLPixabay + "key=" + pixabayAPIKey + "&q=" + encodeURI(city) + "+tourism&image_type=photo");

    const data3 = await resPixabayPhoto.json();
    const cityPhoto = data3.hits[0].webformatURL;

    // id generated by create_UUID function
    const currentId = create_UUID();

    const tripData = {
      cityPhoto: cityPhoto,
      country: countryName,
      date: newDate,
      depDate: depDateFromUser,
      retDate: returnDateFromUser,
      daysLeft: daysLeft,
      weather: weather,
      temp: (daysLeft > 7) ? {
        low_temp: data2.data[0].low_temp,
        max_temp: data2.data[0].max_temp,
        trueOrFalse: true //For the if statement in updateUI in the client side
      } : {
        temp: data2.data[0].temp,
        trueOrFalse: false //For the if statement in updateUI in the client side
      },
      lat: latitude,
      lng: longitude,
      tripId: currentId
    };

    dataOfTripCard[currentId] = tripData;

    return dataOfTripCard;

  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error", error);
    //appropriately handle the error
  }

};
```

Use the props of `BodyOfApp` app that you've connected from redux and pass them to the `getFunc` function.

```
class BodyOfApp extends React.Component {

  performAction = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const { currentInputs } = this.props;

    getFunc(currentInputs).then((dataOfTripCard) => {
      this.props.currentProjectData({
        dataOfTripCard
      })
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      //jsx code here
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  currentInputs: state.inputs.currentInputs
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  // currentInputs: inputs => dispatch(currentInputs(inputs)),
  toggleSubmittedOrNot: popUp => dispatch(toggleSubmittedOrNot(popUp)),
  toggleShowPopUp: () => dispatch(toggleShowPopUp()),
  currentProjectData: projectData => dispatch(currentProjectData(projectData))
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BodyOfApp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because the `getFunc().then((dataOfTripCard) => {...}` arrow function block the scope of `this` in `this.props.currentProjectData({dataOfTripCard})`

A solution to solve it will be to call getFunc() from a regular function which does not block `this` scope.

```
async function getreturnedFunc() {
   try {
           const dataOfTripCard = await getFunc();
           this.props.currentProjectData({dataOfTripCard});
   }catch (e) {
           console.log(e);   
   } 
}

getreturnedFunc();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to drop the `connect` when you are exporting `getFunc`:

```
export default getFunc;
```

`connect` should only be used when you export React components.